# insert semester in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my SQL query there is the column `data_solicitacao`.

I need to insert in SQL a semester rule where the column "semester 1" or "semester 2" will be automatically filled with the number 1 according to the information of the date `data_solicitacao`. The completion of the semester must be automatic according to the current date.

Comment: Can anyone else try to help me? i need it urgently

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generated column. For example:

```
create table t (
  registered date,
  semester int generated always as 
    (case when extract(month from registered) <= 6 then 1 else 2 end) stored
);

insert into t (registered) values (date '2022-01-01');
insert into t (registered) values (date '2022-06-30');
insert into t (registered) values (date '2022-07-01');
insert into t (registered) values (date '2022-12-31');
```

Result:

```
 registered  semester 
 ----------  -------- 
 2022-01-01  1        
 2022-06-30  1        
 2022-07-01  2        
 2022-12-31  2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kwSBRhnzM9GQhWRSHUknXa/0).